# NoSuchMethod on RefreshIndicator

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a layout which is using RefreshIndicator. It's child is CustomScrollView. However when onRefresh handler is called it throws an exception

```
[ERROR:../../lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (21060): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'call' was called on null.
E/flutter (21060): Receiver: null
E/flutter (21060): Tried calling: call()

E/flutter (21060): #0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:43)
E/flutter (21060): #1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:47)
E/flutter (21060): #2      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222)
E/flutter (21060): #3      MyHomePageState.handleRefresh (file:///home/swav/Git/flutter/status-app/lib/state/state.dart:49)
E/flutter (21060): #4      RefreshIndicatorState._show.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/refresh_indicator.dart:319)
E/flutter (21060): #5      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1371)
E/flutter (21060): #6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129)
E/flutter (21060): #7      _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:636)
E/flutter (21060): #8      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665)
E/flutter (21060): #9      _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:478)
E/flutter (21060): #10     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:510)
E/flutter (21060): #11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
E/flutter (21060): #12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)
```

Interesting part is that onRefresh completes successfully.

Also when immediate child of RefreshIndicator was a Flex it wasn't complaining.

Comment: Can you show us the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to debug your issue because you didn't provide your code, but from the stack trace I can see that in your `handleRefresh` method, on line 49 of state.dart, you are calling `new Future.sync(null)`, which is trying to invoke `null` as a function.

Try using `new Future.value(null)` instead when you need a completed `Future` with value `null`. But `RefreshIndicator` doesn't do much when the returned Future completes immediately. You might want to look at this [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/overscroll_demo.dart) for inspiration on how to use `RefreshIndicator`.

It probably wasn't complaining when the child was a `Flex` because a `Flex` doesn't scroll.